# Is it safe to buy smart home products from second hand?

Tags: internet, bluetooth

I wonder if it is safe to buy a smart home product (e.g. Eve Thermo). Because the code on the device, which is needed for pairing, is not changeable. Is it possible that the first owner is still able to control the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the information security part of your question, i.e. whether it is safe to buy smart home products from second hand. Regarding the second part, I admit I have no idea whether Eve Thermo could be reprogrammed properly, but this might be worth asking directly the manufacturer.

Short answer: you're taking more risk buying a used product versus buying new directly from manufacturer. Depending how much money you save, this extra risk might or might not worth the reward.

Long answer: it depends on your definition of safety, but generally this is bad idea if you're concerned about security. Any "smart home" product which had been into skilled hands may be tampered with, and it may be difficult or impossible uncover such tampering. [Here is my Youtube video](https://youtu.be/3jtu9Amm8H0) where I show how a regular keypad electronic lock (not even a "smart" one) can be hijacked, so then it could be opened without typing in a code. Note that there are no visible changes on the lock itself.  This is much easier with "smart" devices which you're going to connect to your network anyway.

The risk of course is lower with Eve Thermo type of devices, but still exists.